# Filter groups based on single condition with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames.
df1

```
    col1
 1  apples
 2 oranges
 3  apples
 4  banana
```

df2

```
   setID    col1
1      1  apples
2      1 oranges
3      1  apples
4      1  banana
5      2  apples
6      2  grapes
7      2 oranges
8      2  apples
9      3 oranges
10     3  grapes
11     3  banana
12     3  banana
13     4  apples
21     4  apples
31     4  banana
41     4 oranges
```

I used filter from dplyr package to narrow down df2 by df1$col1[1] and putting the result in tempdf

```
> tempdf <- df2 %>% filter(df1$col1[1] == df2$col1)
> tempdf
  setID   col1
1     1 apples
2     1 apples
3     2 apples
4     2 apples
5     4 apples
6     4 apples
```

Is there a way I can see all the elements that have the same setID as the matched "apples"? Like this

```
         setID    col1
    1      1  apples
    2      1 oranges
    3      1  apples
    4      1  banana
    5      2  apples
    6      2  grapes
    7      2 oranges
    8      2  apples
    13     4  apples
    21     4  apples
    31     4  banana
    41     4 oranges
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `any` in your `filter` statement, to filter groups where any of the entries for `df2$col1` match the first entry of `df1$col1`.

---

Data:

```
df1 = read.table(text="col1
1  apples
2 oranges
3  apples
4  banana",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 = read.table(text="   setID    col1
1      1  apples
2      1 oranges
3      1  apples
4      1  banana
5      2  apples
6      2  grapes
7      2 oranges
8      2  apples
9      3 oranges
10     3  grapes
11     3  banana
12     3  banana
13     4  apples
21     4  apples
31     4  banana
41     4 oranges",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% group_by(setID) %>% filter(any(col1==df1$col1[1]))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   setID [3]
   setID    col1
   <int>   <chr>
 1     1  apples
 2     1 oranges
 3     1  apples
 4     1  banana
 5     2  apples
 6     2  grapes
 7     2 oranges
 8     2  apples
 9     4  apples
10     4  apples
11     4  banana
12     4 oranges
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I love this solution. I have some ideas on how to run this as a loop to search element by element or in a sliding window manner. I want to ask can such a loop end if there is only one setID remaining. In this case I want the loop to finish when setID=1 remains. It doesnt matter if all of the elements of df1 have been matched to df2 yet.

Comment: Hi @Nix, sorry; as far as I know, this is not possible, a while-loop may be better suited for that purpose.

Comment: I see. The whole purpose of this was to find the setID which matches df1, without having to match the entire df1 against df2. That's why i thought of the filter approach to narrow down element by element. If i were to set a while-loop condition would it go something like "while setID is not unique" run the loop?

Comment: Hi @Nix, I am not really sure what you are asking for. My solution provides the expected output as you described? If you have additional requirements, could you please pose a new question on Stack Overflow, and add the exact desired behavior, as well as input and expected output? That makes it a lot easier to help. Here in the comments is a bit difficult ;)

Comment: Hi @Nix, as I mentioned; please post this as a new question on Stack Overflow rather than changing your old one. That is not a good idea for two reasons; your question will get much less views since it is old, so it is less likely that you will get good answers, and the answers of people who put effort into answering your question are wrong all of a sudden. Thanks!